# Two chrome tabs attached to the same console

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

Is there an easy way to have two different chrome tabs attached to the same console/sources? Something, like a "cloned tab". Sometimes I need to work with two or three different tabs of the same page because I have to test responsiveness, DOM changes, etc, and it would save me a lot of time not having to keep switching from one tab to the other or having to resize them every time.

Comment: No, only the opposite: additional devtools can be opened via `chrome://inspect` in Pages tab.

Comment: I thought so. I looked for browser extensions too, and there is nothing like that. Thanks, anyway!